# Rectangle with cross on title bar

Tags: 14.04, titlebar

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I think that I have found a bug. When I open terminal and  go to edit profile preferences I get a rectangle with a cross on the title bar. It happened with other applications too. Here are the screen shots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Considering filing a bug on LP?

Comment: I want to know whether this is a bug or problem with my graphics drivers

Comment: if you want to know if this is a bug with graphics driver switch driver and see if it is gone. If it is file a bug against the driver package.

Comment: I think this is a bug in unity as in gnome shell it was displayed properly